# Can't reproduce normally distributed random numbers in parallel

Tags: c++, c++11, random, parallel-processing, openmp

I want to generate a reproducible sequence of random numbers in parallel with OpenMP. I wrote a small code that creates for each thread its own RNG with different seed. But when I start generating random numbers in parallel, something strange happens. With uniform distribution I get reproducible results, but with normal distribution i get different results!

More specifically, every time I run the program, the array seems to be shuffled.

My question: Why this might be happening? And how do I resolve this issue?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <omp.h>

int main() {
    std::normal_distribution<> normal(0,1);
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> uniform(0,1);
    std::mt19937 *rng = new std::mt19937[omp_get_max_threads()];
    for(int i = 0; i < omp_get_max_threads(); ++i) {
        rng[i].seed(1+i);
    }

    int N = 100;
    double* arr = new double[N];
#pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        arr[i] = normal(rng[omp_get_thread_num()]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
    }

    delete[] arr;
    delete[] rng;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Your code provides deterministic and repeatable output for both distributions. Of course, the actual values given by `normal` and `uniform` differ, but that is to be expected. Normal distributions will not provide values in the same range, given the same parameters you provided. See the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/normal_distribution/normal_distribution). You have instructed it to use a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1, which means you will have both positive and negative values normally distributed around zero.

Comment: Seeding with `rand()`? That hasn't itself been seeded? That one hurts. Use `std::random_device`.

Comment: @paddy You misunderstood my question, I know that normal and uniform distributions are very different. The problem is that only with a normal distribution my program produces a different result every time I run it.

Comment: @sweenish Why? I want to get the same result every time I run it.

Comment: Side note :  insted of `double* arr = new double[N];` use `std::vector<double> arr(N)` and you will no longer have to manually delete.

Comment: I updated the question with more info on the problem.

Comment: @Peter I'd suggest explicitly seeding with a non-zero constant (e.g. `1+i`) to highlight your desire for a reproducible result.  the values returned by `rand` don't have any stability guarantees

Comment: @SamMason `1+i` didn't help(

Comment: did you read my answer?  it's about making your intent clear to readers on this site.  it's not going to fix your issue, but should help people answer the question in a useful manner rather than distracting them with superfluous issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some implementations of `std::normal_distribution` generate variates two-at-a-time.  They store the second variate in the distribution object and return it the next time it's called.  Having multiple threads accessing the same normal distribution is the likely the reason for seeing non-deterministic results.

`std::uniform_real_distribution` tends not to have any hidden state and hence call the underlying bit generator every time so doesn't exhibit this behaviour.

The existence of [RandomNumberDistribution`.reset()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomNumberDistribution) method hints that it's not safe to share objects between threads.

As suggested in the comments, I'd suggest editing your code so that it doesn't call `rand()` if you want deterministic results.  The way the code is written and what you're asking has different intents and caused me (and other posters) to get confused.

Comment: ?! you just do the same as you're doing for the `mt19937` objects.  I'd suggest using STL containers as well, but that's less of an issue

Comment: Problem solved, as you said it was multiple threads accessing the same normal distribution.